# Editing files on Amazon S3 with collectstatic

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I'm using Amazon S3 to serve my static files. Everything has been set up and when I initially created my CSS files and ran

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

it informed me that everything went fine and my CSS file was copied. Sure enough when viewing the bucket in the browser, it was there. When I edit the file locally and re-run collect static it tells me no static files were copied but 73 were modified. When I check in the browser the changes aren't present in the CSS file; it just looks like the initial version I created.

I figured it'd be a permission error and when I checked I noticed everyone didn't have edit permissions (I know I shouldn't let everyone edit it, but I just want to get it working for the moment). I changed it so everyone could edit, view and download and tried to recollect static but to no avail. The file hadn't been edited.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you try to clean your browser cache and test if any files changed?

Comment: Clearing the cache doesn't do anything. Whenever I push the site to Heroku and it collects the static for me it tells me `0 static files copied, 74 unmodified.` This is despite the fact I just edited a static file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this was pretty bizarre. Effectively the problem was timezones. It thought the files on S3 were younger than the files locally due to time difference discrepancies. I fixed this by editing the TIME_ZONE variable in settings.py with the following:

```
TIME_ZONE = None
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really weird but changing the TIME_ZONE to None worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Django 1.10.6 and I used [this tutorial](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/) to get static files working on S3.

For me `TIME_ZONE = None` didn't work. But this works for me:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
```

So I made a **settings/collectstatic.py** file to run local and sync s3 files to production.